# Bulk delete (custom type) posts that are not visible on website

Tags: custom-post-types

We have a custom post type with over 16.000 posts in database. Each post has a custom meta data 'expiry date'.

We want to regularly delete old posts that have:
1. Expiry date older dan 2 years
AND 2. are not visible on our website

Some 'expired' posts are still shown and I want to make sure these do not get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use MySQL "DELETE".  See this article:

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-join/

So, something like this:

```
DELETE wp_posts, wp_postmeta
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE meta_key = 'expiry date' AND meta_value <= '2017-11-27' AND post_status != 'publish'
```

**NOTE:** 'wp_' could be different depending what your table prefix is set to in your wp-config.php file.

This should get rid of all posts in the posts table and all of the meta records in the meta table.  It will also get rid of drafts/revision.

**DOUBLE NOTE:** -SUPER IMPORTANT- Don't do this unless you have a backup of your database.